# New install - Windows 10 Pro 21H2 Security Tab missing from "Update & Security" & unable to locate Defender Antivirus

Tags: windows-10, security, anti-virus

New install of Windows 10 21H2 from official Micriosoft ISO.

I have two issues.

Issue 1
If I Click Start Button > Settings > Update & Security

Normally the third option down the list on the left hand side is Windows Security but it is missing.

Issue 2
I am doubtful that Defender Antivirus has been installed as if I search (using task bar)
for "Defender Antivirus" or just "Antivirus" nothing is returned.

However Defender Firewall IS installed and I can open it via the search.

I have carefully looked at the Defender Antivirus policys in Group Policy Editor
and "Enable headless UI mode" is set to disabled as is "Turn Off Defender Antivirus".

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Since new install, try DISM and SFC:   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test....   See if that helps  ... Then see if you can update and run ALL updates

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No 2 completed with no errors, No 3 could not find the image path so failed, No 3 found some currupt files and after repair windows update no longer works.

Comment: The DISM absolutely should have worked. I am confused did it run or did it not run? You listed “no 3” twice with conflicting descriptions. How new of an installation is it? Based on what you describe, if errors are being found, it’s likely corrupt and you should just perform a repair install

Comment: With a new install, I would be surprised if you have a virus (@Harrymc's suggestion).  First as @Ramhound has suggested (and DISM did not work) do a Repair Install from the Media Creation Link:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0):

Your computer has probably been infected with a virus that sabotaged
Windows Security.

I would suggest to backup your data (NOT Windows itself),
format the disk and install Windows from scratch.

This is the safest method for getting rid of the virus and fixing any
damage that it might have done.

Be careful with the applications that you install, one of them
might contain a virus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  install security center

Open powershell and type:

> Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage

Hit enter and let it fetch and install, reboot and see if av shows in the security center properly now.